# Javascript condition always false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a website where I use AngularJS elements such as `md-input-container` and `md-datepicker`.

I wrote (with the help of my teacher) a javascript program shown below, it allows me to know if the user has typed the right information in the inputs and has chosen the right date.

```
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller

('AppCtrl', function() {
  var ctrl = this;
  this.aller = "";
  this.retour = "";
  this.date;

  this.checkValue = function() {

    if((this.aller.toLowerCase()=="montpellier" &&     this.retour.toLowerCase()=="marseille")
      && (this.date != null && this.date.toString() == "Fri Jun 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200")) {
      document.location.href="recherche.html";
    }
  else
  {
    alert("Veuillez saisir Montpellier et Marseille, et le 10 juin 2016");
  }
}
});
```

If the condition is true, when the user clicks a button it brings him to the "recherche.html" page. However, even if when condition is respected it still shows the alert.

Comment: how is checkValue called?  post the relevant code

Comment: that isn't possible. the values probably aren't what you think they are when the function is called.

Comment: @Rooster <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="ctrl.checkValue()">Trouver</md-button>

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
var ctrl = this;
```

is important. It saves the value of `this` for later use. For times when `this` might refer to something *else* than the controller.

That moment is when you use `this` inside the other function. Inside that function, use `ctrl` instead of `this`, and you should be good to go.

Here's a full demo:

```js
angular.module('BlankApp', [])
  .controller('AppCtrl', function() {
    var ctrl = this;
  
    ctrl.aller = "montpellier";
    ctrl.retour = "marseille";
    ctrl.date = "Fri Jun 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200";

    ctrl.checkValue = function() {
      if (ctrl.aller.toLowerCase() === "montpellier" 
          && ctrl.retour.toLowerCase() === "marseille"
          && !!ctrl.date 
          && ctrl.date.toString() === "Fri Jun 10 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0200") {
        alert('Will do: document.location.href = "recherche.html";');
      } else {
        alert("Veuillez saisir Montpellier et Marseille, et le 10 juin 2016");
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="BlankApp">
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
    Aller: <input ng-model="ctrl.aller"><br>
    Retour: <input ng-model="ctrl.retour"><br>
    Date: <input ng-model="ctrl.date"><br>
    <button ng-click="ctrl.checkValue()">checkValue</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Several notes on things that I have also tweaked:

- You have a dependency in your app that is not needed for the question (which makes it harder for others to help you);
- The spacing of your code makes it very hard to read or debug;
- You're unclear on what you want with `date`. At any rate, comparing `Date`s or any `Date` stuff in Javascript is *very* tricky, and if you have to do a lot of it I recommend looking into momentjs. At any rate, I've simplified the code down to `date` being a string because your question was not about that part, but I do suspect it'll cause you troubles;
- There were a lot of parentheses inside the `if` clause that made it hard to read;
- Always prefer `===` over `==` if at all possible;
- A suggestion: use `!!ctrl.date` to check for falsy values instead of `!==` (or worse: `!=`) comparisons with `null`;
- When you have the `ctrl = this` idiom, I recommend not using `this` anymore at all even where it is safe (e.g. on the three plain properties), but use `ctrl.` there instead as well as I've shown.

To make the runnable demo clearer I set some defaults on the view model values, and replaced the redirect with an `alert`.

Comment: hmm.... wouldn't that in theory cause the alert to never happen, due to a syntax error? `undefined is not a function` or similar

Comment: You make a point Kevin B, even if i type something else than the conditions required, the alert box doesn't appear

Comment: @Jeroen Thank you for giving attention to my problem. I solved it a couple of hours ago but my connection has been cut thus I couldn't post. The problem is that the ctrl.date value was supported by Mozilla (because my teacher tested in a Mozilla browser). I had to add "(Europe centrale - heure d’été)" so it could work on Chrome. And I think  I will add an if condition for Mozilla browser

Comment: Working intensively with dates/times in Javascript can be *horrible*, and *horrific* if it has to work cross-browser. Do yourself a favor and have a look at the suggested [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library, or something equivalent.